# Should I use Ubuntu fonts in Web App and Mobile Apps?

Tags: web-app, interface, users, font

I am designing Secured Web App and mobile app and I'm really concerned about using the Ubuntu font family as most of the web apps are using Open Sans or PT Sans (or some sort of sans-serif)

I really would like to make it as easy to read but look professional, branded and most secure as possible.

Font sizes I will be using are: 12px, 13px, 14px, 16px, 18px and 24px

Comment: Why do you want to use that specific font family? Because of the way it looks? You also mention being 'branded'; Do you need it to be branded to Ubuntu?

Comment: How can a font be super secure...

Comment: @BDD Ubuntu and Open Sans are just a personal preference, but of course I don't want to use a font just because I like it. So I asked a question. Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a valid UX question here if all you're asking for is opinions on fonts.

Comment: what exactly is your concern?

Answer (score 0):

This font made by [Bruno Maag](http://www.myfonts.com/newsletters/cc/201209.html), well-known professional font designer. This font is a great alternative to `Open Sans` and `PT Sans`.

You should think more about UX, not font typeface.

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't matter what fonts other websites use
2. There is no such thing as unsecure font
3. Ubuntu Font is a very well made font which would be a good fit for your desired usage and is provided by [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu) so you don't have to host it yourself.
4. **It really comes down to personal preference** whether you like the typeface or not.